# File isn't saving into fb laravel-5.8

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

I am trying to upload files in DB but they are not saving into DB, or the page isn't showing any error.

**Controller**

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    request()->validate([
        'file' => 'required',
    ]);

    $upload = $request->file('file');
    $path = $upload->store('public/storage');
    $file = File::create([
        'filename' => $file->getClientOrignalName(),
        'path' => $path
    ]);

    return redirect('/file')->with('success', 'File Uploaded Successfully');
}
```

**Routes**

```php
Route::get('/file','FileController@index')->name('viewfile');
Route::get('/file/upload','FileController@create')->name('formfile');
Route::post('/file/upload','FileController@store')->name('uploadfile');
```

**Blade file:**

```php
<form method="post" action="{{ route('uploadfile') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="file" name="filename" multiple="multiple">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button>
    <a href="{{ route('viewfile') }}" class="btn btn-success">Back</a>
</form>
```

**Model**

```php
protected $fillable = [
    'filename', 'path'
];
```

Any solution?

Comment: the form input in blade is named `name="filename"` and in your controller you are tryin to work over a `$request->file('file')`. Choose the input name you want an use the same in blade and controller

Comment: now it says:   Call to a member function store() on null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are uploading multiple files then your input name should be an array.

```
<input type="file" name="filename[]" multiple="multiple">
```

You are accessing the file by incorrect name, hence your upload should be

```
$upload = $request->file('filename');
```

and your filename would be

```
'filename' => $request->filename->getClientOriginalName()
```

Comment: by implementing the above code: it says:    Call to a member function getClientOrignalName() on null

Comment: renamed `file` to `filename` . Try again with the updated code

Comment: Method Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile::getClientOrignalName does not exist.

Comment: there is a typo, **`getOriginalName()`** An `i` is missing in your method name